# How to reposition or reorder the keys in JSON object or hash map in java

Tags: java, json, hashmap

```js
{
data:{},
firstNane:"",
id:"1,
lastName:"",
  children:[
    parent:"1",
    id:"11",
    name:"",
    firstName:"",
    lastName:"",
    chidlren:[..other nested children],
    data:{},
  ],
name:"",
}
```

Above is my JSON object, I want to reposition the keys into the following format
id,name,firstName,lastName,data and children

Could some one let me know how can I do the reposition the keys as mentioned above so my final output would be display as follows ::-

This is the JSON object also let me know how it would be possible for the hash map to order the elements.

```js
{
    id:"1,
    name:"",
    firstNane:"",
    lastName:"",
    data:{},
      children:[
        id:"11",
        name:"",
        firstName:"",
        lastName:"",
        parent:"1",
        data:{},
        chidlren:[..other nested children],
      ],

}
```

Comment: A JSON object is an array. All you need is to insert them in the order you want. There's no easy way to reorder the elements in a JSON object. This is because the structure of a JSON string is not strict like (for instance) XML. XML enforces these sort things. I know JSON is the new thing, but if this is important 1) Use something like XML so that things can be arranged in a specific way regardless of order of insertion, or 2) Write your own JSON writer.

Comment: You have not provided enough details.  Answer at least these:  How are you generating the JSON (include code)?  What tool are you using to generate the JSON (gson, jackson, something else)?  How do you represent the data in your java code (include the class or classes; maybe just the children stuff class)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [JSON definition](https://www.json.org/json-en.html):

> JSON is built on two structures:
> A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an *object*, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.
> An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an *array*, vector, list, or sequence.
>
> An object is an **unordered** set of name/value pairs.

Similarly, [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) is not ordered either: *This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.*

Next, the presented JSON is invalid and needs to be updated.

However, certain JSON libraries provide facilities to sort the fields for example, [`@JsonPropertyOrder`](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations) annotation in Jackson library.

```java
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "name", "firstName", "lastName", "parent", "data", "children" })
@Data
public class MyPojo {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Map<String, Object> data;
    private List<MyPojo> children;
    private Integer parent;
}
```

Test:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyPojo c1 = new MyPojo(11, "", "", "", new HashMap<>(), new ArrayList<>(), 1);
MyPojo mp = new MyPojo(1, "", "", "", new HashMap<>(), Arrays.asList(c1), null);

System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(mp));
```

Output:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "",
  "firstName" : "",
  "lastName" : "",
  "data" : { },
  "children" : [ {
    "id" : 11,
    "name" : "",
    "firstName" : "",
    "lastName" : "",
    "parent" : 1,
    "data" : { },
    "children" : [ ]
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order the elements using a `LinkedHashMap`.

The `LinkedHashMap` returns the elements in the same way they are added, unlike `HashMap`.